# How to get KeyChar in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a simple app, where user types in text and presses Enter, then the text is displayed on  big TV Screen.

The question : how to get `e.KeyChar` in WPF app, KeyUp Event ? 
Or is there another way ?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyUp += MainWindow_KeyUp;
        }

        private String Text;

        void MainWindow_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                TextLabel.Content = Text;
                Text = String.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                Text += e.Key;
            }

        }
```

The results when I type in "test" is "TEST".
Do I have to manually handle all the system keys ? What If I want to type "Test" -> now I get the result "RihgtShiftTEST". All I want is to accumulate a buffer of chars, and the display the text.

Comment: Could help a look to e.Modifiers in event handler? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.modifiers.aspx

Comment: Yep, it would help. I'm kinda shocked and surprised that I'd have to do this manually, and that functionality that used to work in WindowsForms doesn't any more

Comment: Do you have to accumulate the buffer invisibly? Can it be in another window (on another screen)?

Comment: Does it matter ? The idea is to do that invisibly

Comment: you can use keydown event,rampapam rampapam rampapam keydown rampapam rampapam keydown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading text input it's best to use the following event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ontextinput.aspx

The "Text" member of the TextCompositionEventArgs already provides high-level plain text and filters out all the nasty control characters, etc.