# Trap NULL key in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a barcode scanner and we were looking for a way to determine if input was from a keyboard or the scanner. The input will be used in a WPF POS application. We thought we had come up with a good method by using the scanners ability to prefix reads with custom characters. The first character ideally would be non printable so we chose NULL or '\0'. We used the following code to register an event handler

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Control), System.Windows.Controls.Control.KeyUpEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(KeyUpEvent));

internal static void KeyUpEvent (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyEventArgs keyEvent = e as KeyEventArgs;

        if (keyEvent != null)
        {
            keyEvent.Key.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This however seems to not get the first NULL character and instead moves to the next char which is the length of the data.

I have also tested with a console app and just done a Console.ReadKey(). This returns me the null char as the first thing read so I know the scanner is definitely sending the correct data.

So is there any way in WPF to obtain all the data read?

**Edit:**

I tried using TextCompositionEventHandler but to no avail, i still only get the printable characters coming through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[KeyEventArgs.Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.key%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is *not* a character, it's an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) indicating which key was pressed. There is no `NULL` keyboard key so there is no point trying to check for the ASCII NULL (0x00) character. Moreover, most non-printable characters have no equivalent key and require the user to use a combination of keys to type them.

If you want to detect scanner codes using prefixes, try chekcing the [UIElement.TextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.textinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [TextBoxBase.TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events.

A better idea may be to use the scanner's SDK (if available) to send data directly to your application. More expensive models usually have an SDK to communicate with applications directly instead of emulating the keyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately the scanner choice isn't down to me and the support is pretty limited other than the manual so no SDK :(

Comment: Second question is will UIElement.TextInput work regardless of which control has focus?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I don't think NULL and \0 is the same in this context. Have a look at this post. They suggest using TextInput instead of KeyUp.

[How to get KeyChar in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426303/how-to-get-keychar-in-wpf-application)